# Merging Pairs of Elements in List Based on Sequence

Tags: r, list, merge

I am working with data collected from respondents at two time points. Each data-set for each respondent is stored as a separate file. I have 42 respondents, so I have 84 files total. I have compiled all of these files into an 84-element list, where each element of the list is a data-frame.

Because of how the files were named, the first element of the list contains data from the first time-point on respondent A, and the second element contains data from the second-time point on respondent A. The third element contains data from from the first time-point on respondent B, and the fourth element contains data from the second time-point on respondent B. Etc.

I am trying to figure out how to create a loop that will merge the first and second elements, the third and fourth elements, etc., so that my 84-element list is reduced to a 42-element list.

Here is some example code. In this example, each respondent is represented by values in the vector "ID", the respondent's exercise partners are listed in the vector "Names," and the bodyweight of these exercise partners is listed in the vector "Weight" and "Weight2":

```
Names <- c("Kevin", "Rich", "Frank")
ID <- c("A1", "A1", "A1")
Weight <- c(159, 200, 186)
df1 <- data.frame(ID, Names, Weight)

Names <- c("Kevin", "Rich", "Frank", "Kip", "Earl")
ID <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1")
Weight2 <- c(170, 180, 190, 240, 255)
df2 <- data.frame(ID, Names, Weight2)

Names <- c("Sam", "Tim", "Bill", "Bobby")
ID <- c("B2", "B2", "B2", "B2")
Weight <- c(105, 155, 177, 310)
df3 <- data.frame(ID, Names, Weight)

Names <- c("Sam", "Eric", "Donald")
ID <- c("B2", "B2", "B2")
Weight2 <- c(120, 100, 205)
df4 <- data.frame(ID, Names, Weight2)

example_list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

example_merge1 <- merge.data.frame(df1, df2, by.x = "Names", by.y = "Names", all = TRUE)

example_merge2 <- merge.data.frame(df3, df4, by.x = "Names", by.y = "Names", all = TRUE)
```

My list looks similar to the list created in the code above labeled "example_list," and I am trying to figure out how to run a merge loop over the list object so that it creates merged data-frames that appear in "example_merge1" and "example_merge2".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea via base R,

```
m1 <- matrix(seq_along(example_list), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

lapply(split(m1, seq(nrow(m1))), function(i) 
                   merge(example_list[i[1]], example_list[i[2]], by = 'Names', all = TRUE))
```

Which gives,

> ```
> $`1`
>   Names ID.x Weight ID.y Weight2
> 1 Frank   A1    186   A1     190
> 2 Kevin   A1    159   A1     170
> 3  Rich   A1    200   A1     180
> 4  Earl <NA>     NA   A1     255
> 5   Kip <NA>     NA   A1     240
>
> $`2`
>    Names ID.x Weight ID.y Weight2
> 1   Bill   B2    177 <NA>      NA
> 2  Bobby   B2    310 <NA>      NA
> 3    Sam   B2    105   B2     120
> 4    Tim   B2    155 <NA>      NA
> 5 Donald <NA>     NA   B2     205
> 6   Eric <NA>     NA   B2     100
> ```